# Kivy ScreenManager gives me a black screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have been trying to create a ping pong game using kivy. I followed the [tutorial on their website](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html) and it worked perfectly! However I wanted to add a start screen. I looked on Google and saw that I should use Kivy's Screen Manager. I put it in my code but however when I press the start button it just does nothing and gives me a black screen. I have been trying to figure it out, but I do not see what is wrong! Probably becuase I do not have much experience with Kivy. Here is my code.

***main.py***

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

class PingPongPaddle(Widget):

    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset
class PingPongBall(Widget):
    #Velocity on x and y axis
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)

    #So ball.velocity can be used
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    #Moves the ball one step
    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

class PingPongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)


    def serve_ball(self, vel=(8, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel
    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        #Bounce off the paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        #Bounce off top and bottom
        if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        #Went off the side
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        #To sense if screen is touched
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y

class GameScreen(Screen):
    def play(self):
        global game
        game = PingPongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        #Runs every 60th of a second
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        return game

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass



class PingPongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition=SlideTransition())

        screen_manager.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(GameScreen(name="game"))
        return screen_manager




if __name__ == "__main__":
    PingPongApp().run()
```

***pingpong.kv***

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Start!"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "game"
<GameScreen>:
    on_enter: self.play()

<PingPongBall>:
    size: 75, 75
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size          

<PingPongPaddle>:
    size: 50, 400
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size

<PingPongGame>:
    ball: PingPong_ball
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 20, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 140  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player1.score)

    Label:
        font_size: 140 
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player2.score)

    Label:
        font_size: 35
        center_x: root.width * 6/7
        top: root.top - 500
        text: "by Me"

    PingPongBall:
        id: PingPong_ball
        center: self.parent.center

    PingPongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y

    PingPongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width - self.width
        center_y: root.center_y
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by including this line in the GameScreen's play function.

```
self.add_widget(game)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new around here, but I think this may help When I use Kivy I also import the "screen" and use that. Here it is:

```
        self.removeuser = RemoveUser()
    screen = Screen(name="RemoveUser") # This will be the naem of screen to be called
    screen.add_widget(self.removeuser)
    self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)
```

That should then work, return the self.screen_manager 
Then for your Start button make a function which does

```
PingPongApp.screen_manger.current = "<name of start screen>"
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but this did not work for me. It gives me the same screen as before